# Get average of the top N values for each row from a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, average

I have a multidimensional array of students 'name' and 'scores':

```
$student = array(
    'Alice' => array(84, 93, 88, 100, 92, 84) ,
    'bob' => array(92, 47, 68, 79, 89) , 
    'charlie' => array(73, 85, 84, 69, 67, 92) , 
    'denis' => array(59, 92, 83, 79, 73) , 
    'eve' => array(91, 68, 85, 79, 84)
);
```

Now, I want to find the average of highest 'five' marks of each student:

```
foreach ($students as $student => $key) {
    echo $student . '<br>';

    arsort($key);

    $value   = array_slice($key, 0,5);

    foreach ($value as $output){
        $total    += $output . '<br />';

        $average   = $total / count($value);

    }
    echo $average . '<br/>';
}
```

My problem is, instead of giving the average of all the students, it is giving the average of only first student 'Alice'. What should I do to get the average of all students?

Comment: for one you are calculating the average inside of the same loop that is generating the total. This should actually be outside that inner loop (where you echo the average).

Comment: I think the question is a bit ambigous. Are you asking to get the average of each student's top 5 grades? Or are you asking to get the average of all students' top 5 grades collectively?

Comment: get average of each student's top 5 grades #Sherif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems, but just replace your inner `foreach()` with:

```
$average = array_sum($value) / count($value);
```

So:

```
foreach ($students as $student => $key){
    echo $student . '<br>';
    arsort($key);
    $value   = array_slice($key, 0,5);
    $average = array_sum($value) / count($value);
    echo $average . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: one more thing, what if we don't want to use the php functions 'arsort' for sorting, 'array_slice' for limiting array and 'array_sum'.. How we'll do the same program without using these functions ?? using loops or if_conditions ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the following code can be used to add each student's top 5 scores to an array, and then average that array.

```
$scores = array();

foreach ($students as $student => $key){

     // Sort this student's scores
     arsort($key);

     // Add the top 5 scores to the scores array
     $scores = array_merge($scores, array_slice($key, 0,5));

}

// Average of all the top 5 scores
$average =  array_sum($scores) / count($scores);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three main problems with the approach you're currently taking.

1. You are overwriting the value of `$average` with each iteration of the loop
2. You are calculating the average `N` times for each score
3. You're incorrectly stating the average as `SUM([score1...score5]) / N`

Here is the correct implementation of the average of the top 5 scores of each student:

```
$students = [
    'Alice'   => [84, 93, 88, 100, 92, 84],
    'bob'     => [92, 47, 68, 79, 89],
    'charlie' => [73, 85, 84, 69, 67, 92],
    'denis'   => [59, 92, 83, 79, 73],
    'eve'     => [91, 68, 85, 79, 84],
];

$averages = array_map(function($scores) {
    arsort($scores);
    return array_sum(array_slice($scores, 0, 5)) / 5;
}, $students);

var_dump($averages);

/* this gives us something like ... 
array(5) {
  ["Alice"]=>
  float(91.4)
  ["bob"]=>
  int(75)
  ["charlie"]=>
  float(80.6)
  ["denis"]=>
  float(77.2)
  ["eve"]=>
  float(81.4)
}
*/
```

Notice that to say `$average = array_sum(array_slice($scores, 0, 5)) / count($scores)` is actually **incorrect**, since you are only averaging the top `5` scores, you need not divide by `count($scores)` but by `5` instead.